# Evaluation by methods of complex analysis $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1} \mathrm{dx}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How would we evaluate the below integral by methods of complex analysis?

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x^2+1} \mathrm{dx}$$

I asked [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155941/evaluate-the-integral-int-01-frac-lnx1x21-dx) a while ago, but at that time I didn't specify this requirement.
Now, I'm only interested in a complex way. Thanks !!!

Sis.

Comment: Hmmm, or I should use the fact that $x^2+1=(x-i)(x+i)$ and then $\frac{1}{x^2+1}= \frac{1}{2 x} (\frac{1}{x-i}+\frac{1}{x+i})$

Comment: This problem is a special case of the [more general problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188732/methods-to-evaluate-int-a-b-frac-ln-left-tx-u-right-mx/188828#188828)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^2+1}dx=
\left[\begin{array}{l}
t=\frac{1}{x} \\
dt=-\frac{1}{x^2}dx
\end{array}\right]=\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(t+1)-\ln{t}}{1+t^2}dt=
\left[\begin{array}{l}
u=t-1 \\
du=dt
\end{array}\right] =
\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(u+2)-\ln(u+1)}{1+(u+1)^2}du.
$$

I am quite confident that this integral can be handled with a keyhole contour in much a similar way as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282014/evaluating-real-integral-using-residue-calculus-why-different-results) integral. If you want me to do more details, just comment, and I will update when I have the time.

---

EDIT: Continued the argument. Please notify me about misprints or other errors.
I will show how to compute
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x+2)}{1+(x+1)^2}dx$$
(the other one is solved analogously).

[image: Keyhole contour]

We now consider the integral
$$\int_C \frac{\log^2(z+2)}{1+(z+1)^2}dz,$$
where $C$ is the keyhole contour above. Note the choice of logarithm! It is imperative that we take $0<\arg{z}<2\pi$ for the logarithms (or $2\pi n<\arg{z}<2\pi (n+1)$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$).

The integrand has poles at $z=-1\pm i$, and by Cauchy's integral formula, we get
$$
\int_C \frac{\log^2(z+2)}{1+(z+1)^2}dz=
\int_C \frac{\log^2(z+2)}{(z+1+i)(z+1-i)}dz=
2\pi i\left(\frac{\log^2(1-i)}{-2i}+
\frac{\log^2(1+i)}{2i}\right)=
\pi(\log^2(1+i)-\log^2(1-i))=
\pi\left(\left(\ln\sqrt{2}+\frac{i\pi}{4}\right)^2-\left(\ln\sqrt{2}+\frac{7i\pi}{4}\right)^2\right)=
\frac{6\pi^3-3i\pi^2\ln{2}}{2}
.$$

The integral along $\gamma$ goes to zero as the inner radius goes to zero, and the integral along $\Gamma$ goes to zeros as $R\rightarrow\infty$ (this can be shown using the ML-inequality).

Therefore, in the limit we only get contributions from the straight parts, so
$$
\int_0^R\frac{\log^2(x+i\varepsilon+1)}{(1+x+i\varepsilon)^2+1}dx+
\int_R^0\frac{\log^2(x-i\varepsilon+1)}{(1+x-i\varepsilon)^2+1}dx\rightarrow \frac{6\pi^3-3i\pi^2\ln{2}}{2}.
$$
But we also have
$$
\int_0^R\frac{\log^2(x+i\varepsilon+2)}{(1+x+i\varepsilon)^2+1}dx+
\int_R^0\frac{\log^2(x-i\varepsilon+2)}{(1+x-i\varepsilon)^2+1}dx\rightarrow
\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2(x+2)-\left(\ln(x+2)+2i\pi\right)^2}{(1+x)^2+1}dx=
\int_0^\infty\frac{4\pi^2-4i\pi\ln(x+2)}{(1+x)^2+1}dx,
$$
so
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{4\pi^2-4i\pi\ln(x+2)}{(1+x)^2+1}dx=\frac{6\pi^3-3i\pi^2\ln{2}}{2}.$$
By considering the imaginary part, we get that
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x+2)}{(x+1)^2+1}dx=\frac{3\pi\ln{2}}{8}.$$

It is possible to compute
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(x+1)}{(x+1)^2+1}dx$$
analogously, and then take the difference in order to find the value of the original integral.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you might add more details. Thanks. (+1)

Comment: I will continue the argument when time allows, then.

Comment: Sure, no problem. There is no hurry for me.

Comment: I would really be interested to see if this works. I have a contour integral, but only after a pretty difficult substitution.

Comment: @MårtenW: thank you for your work! It'll be a good lesson to me in terms of complex analysis.

Comment: @MårtenW I like the figure, which program did you use to draw it?

Comment: @Mercy: This particular one was done in $\LaTeX$ and tikzpicture, and quite long ago. Nowadays I usually find Asymptote (http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) easier though.

Comment: @MårtenW Something is wrong here. The integrand isn't holomorphic (or even defined) at $z = -2$ ($\log(0)$) and this point is inside the contour. I don't think the residue theorem applies.

Comment: @PeterM: Yes there are clearly some major problems. The entire branch cut (the ray starting at $z=-2$ and going rightward along the real axis) should be outside the contour, and this changes the limits in the integrals along the straight parts. I shall see if I can remedy this, otherwise I feel obliged to remove the answer.

Answer (score 11):

Well, there is a method which is not *that* complex.

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}dx$$

$$\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^x \frac{1}{1+y}dy\right)\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^x \frac{1}{1+y}dy\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$

Make a change of variables $y=ux$ in the inner integral:

$$\tag 1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+ux}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dudx$$

Partial fractions:

$${x \over {1 + xu}}{1 \over {1 + {x^2}}} = {1 \over {1 + {u^2}}}{x \over {1 + {x^2}}} + {u \over {1 + {u^2}}}{1 \over {1 + {x^2}}} - {u \over {1 + {u^2}}}{1 \over {1 + xu}}$$

Now, integrating the first two terms, which account to the same$^1$, gives that you integral is

$$\mathcal I=\frac \pi 4\log 2-\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac u {1+u^2}\frac{1}{1+xu}dxdu$$

The latter integral is just our original integral, due to symmetry, as you see in $(1)$

This means that $$\mathcal I =\frac \pi 8 \log 2$$

as desired. You can see a simlar integral solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117246/evaluation-of-the-integral-int-01-frac-ln1-x1-xdx/117340#117340) with the very same method.

$1$: symmetry, once again.

Comment: Nicely done! (+1)

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: nice solution. (+1)

Comment: I think your fractions-decomposition is slightly incorrect, and it should be:${x \over {1 + xu}}{1 \over {1 + {x^2}}} = {1 \over {1 + {u^2}}}{x \over {1 + {x^2}}} + {u \over {1 + {u^2}}}{1 \over {1 + {x^2}}} - {u \over {1 + {u^2}}}{1 \over {1 + xu}}$

Comment: @awllower You're right. I forgot the $x$ on the right hand side. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a real method, and since $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}\dots$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^{\pi/4}\log(1+\tan(u))\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/4}\Big(\log(\cos(u)+\sin(u))-\log(\cos(u))\Big)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/4}\Big(\log(\sqrt2\cos(\pi/4-u))-\log(\cos(u))\Big)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/4}\Big(\log(\sqrt2)+\log(\cos(\pi/4-u))-\log(\cos(u))\Big)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac\pi8\log(2)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Another method, avoiding all trig substitutions, and using contour integration**

Suppose that
$$
(1+x)(1+y)=2\tag{2}
$$
That is,
$$
x=\frac{1-y}{1+y}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}=-\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+y^2}\tag{3}
$$
Furthermore, $(2)$ implies
$$
\log\left(\frac{1+x}{\sqrt2}\right)=-\log\left(\frac{1+y}{\sqrt2}\right)\tag{4}
$$
Substituting, using $(3)$ and $(4)$, remembering to flip the limits of integration, yields
$$
\int_0^1\log\left(\frac{1+x}{\sqrt2}\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}=-\int_0^1\log\left(\frac{1+y}{\sqrt2}\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+y^2}\tag{5}
$$
Noting that the left and right sides of $(5)$ are equal yet opposite, we see that both are $0$. Unraveling yields
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\frac{\log(\sqrt2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
To evaluate $(6)$ note that the substitution $x\mapsto\frac1x$ yields
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}=\int_1^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}\tag{7}
$$
and since $\frac1{1+x^2}$ is even we get
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}=\frac14\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}\tag{8}
$$
Let $\gamma$ be the contour following the real line on $[-R,R]$ and circling back counterclockwise in the upper half-plane along $|z|=R$, we get
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^2}=\int_\gamma\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{1+z^2}\tag{9}
$$
There is one singularity in the upper half-plane at $z=i$ with residue $\frac1{2i}$ which means the value of the integral along $\gamma$ is $2\pi i\cdot\frac1{2i}=\pi$. Using $(6)$, $(8)$, and $(9)$, this yields
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\frac{\log(\sqrt2)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\log(\sqrt2)\cdot\frac14\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\log(\sqrt2)\cdot\frac14\cdot\pi\\
&=\frac\pi8\log(2)\tag{10}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks (+1). However, I'd be more interested in a complex method. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't looked at your link to see that you already got an answer to this integral.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: "...and since $\Bbb R\subset \Bbb C$" +1

Comment: See my answer! ${}{}$

Comment: @robjohn: I can't upvote you 2 times on the same question but ... :D

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals I have modified the second answer to use contour integration (avoiding all trig substitutions).

Comment: The method you apply using $(1+x)(1+y)=2$ is utterly amazing, again!

Comment: Another way to continue the trig substitution method would be $$\int_{0}^{\pi / 4} \ln(1+\tan u) du = \int_{0}^{\pi / 4} \ln(1 + \tan (\frac{\pi}{4} - u)) du = \int_{0}^{\pi / 4} \ln(\frac{2}{1 + \tan u}) du$$ and then use log properties to split the integral