# Evaluate the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{\log x \arctan x}{x}\right)^2 \ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Some rumours point out that the integral you see might be evaluated in a 
straightforward way.
But rumours are sometimes just rumours. Could you confirm/refute it?

$$
\int_0^{\infty}\left[\frac{\log\left(x\right)\arctan\left(x\right)}{x}\right]^{2}
\,{\rm d}x
$$

**EDIT**
W|A tells the integral evaluates $0$ but this is not true.
Then how do I exactly compute it?

Comment: Wow - even though, as Isaac says, it's non-negative (zero at $x=1$) even Wolfram|Alpha [says so](http://bit.ly/15IubvH)!

Comment: The function is non-negative, positive and continuous (except perhaps at the origin). I don't think that the integral should be zero, even if that is what WA is indicating. Then again, if you change the integral from 0 to 5, for example, you get a positive number. Perhaps this is an error on WA?

Comment: @Isaac - I suppose so, and it doesn't have the "Show step-by-step solution" like it usually does

Comment: @IsaacSolomon: W|A insists is $0$. Why? Then if it's not $0$ what is its real value?

Comment: Also if you just write ["integral of (the function)"](http://bit.ly/14nBWLF) into W|A, under "Definite integrals" it says the value is 6.200200821...

Comment: Mathematica agrees that the definite integral should be zero (yet clearly it should not be, as Isaac's comment explains).  Cool! I've seen this before - usually it is due to Wolfram's integration methods (complex functions are employed).  Report it to Wolfram, sometimes you can get a free T-shirt out of it!

Comment: @user68326 I would follow the suggestion in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279372/a-limit-wrong-using-wolfram-alpha#comment609678_279372) comment if I were you.

Comment: @icurays1 I smile at this coincidence. Yet I weep knowing I haven't won the lottery yet.

Comment: I don't understand why everyone is upvoting this question. It was posed as a riddle, without any indication that the "rumours" refer to Wolfram|Alpha; if WChargin hadn't told us about the Wolfram|Alpha bug, the question would have made no sense whatsoever. I downvoted.

Comment: @IsaacSolomon You should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: I originally upvoted, @joriki, but agree now that the question was deceptive in light of how it all turned out. My vote is locked in, though. +1 for your comment.

Comment: @user68326 your phrasing in terms of "rumours" without attributing it to WA was deceptive. calling him frustrated is rude on top of that. why don't *you* prove it, or show why you think this had a hope of being evaluated in a straightforward manner.

Comment: @Lepidopterist: do you know what is rude? To know nothing about mathematics but to spread your opinions here as they are valuable opinions. This is rude. Perhaps you're another frustrated.

Comment: @user68326 Regardless of how good at maths people here are, there's no need for personal attacks. I suggest you delete your offensive comments towards other users. On a side note: I sure hope people here are good at maths, because if they aren't, then I must be a very, very, very dumb person as I know close to nothing when compared to the average user here.

Comment: Who wants a Wolfram tee-shirt anyway?

Comment: @julien: I offer the Wolfram tee-shirt to you. Just send them an email with the issue.

Answer (score 41):

Related problems: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290200/int-0-infty-frac-ln-xx2a2-mathrmdx-evaluate-integral), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294383/evaluate-int-0-infty-left-fracx-textex-texte-x/295326#295326), [(III)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188418/elementary-derivation-of-certian-identites-related-to-the-riemannian-zeta-functi). Denoting our integral by $J$ and recalling the mellin transform
$$ F(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1} f(x)\,dx  \implies  F''(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{s-1} \ln(x)^2\,f(x)\,dx.$$

Taking $f(x)=\arctan(x)^2$, then the mellin transform of $f(x)$ is

$$ \frac{1}{2}\,{\frac {\pi \, \left( \gamma+2\,\ln\left( 2 \right) +\psi
\left( \frac{1}{2}+\frac{s}{2} \right)\right) }{s\sin \left( \frac{\pi \,s}{2}
\right)}}-\frac{1}{2}\,{\frac {{\pi }^{2}}{s\cos\left( \frac{\pi \,s}{2}
 \right) }},$$

where $\psi(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\ln \Gamma(x)$ is the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function). Thus $J$ can be calculated directly as

$$ J= \lim_{s\to -1} F''(s) = \frac{1}{12}\,\pi \, \left( 3\,{\pi }^{2}\ln  \left( 2 \right) -{\pi }^{2}+24
\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) -3\,\zeta  \left( 3 \right)  \right)\sim 6.200200824 .$$

Comment: You seem like the best around here (I saw some of your answers). Why aren't you upvoted?

Comment: Because there is much envy on MSE as I can see. What kind of people come here, really?

Comment: @user68326: Thank you very much for your comment. I really appreciate it. I am happy that many people are benefited of my answers.

Comment: How did you get the Mellin transform of $\large\arctan\left(x\right)$ ?.

Comment: $\large\tt Mathematica$ yields your result $\large\sim 6.2002$ with $\large\tt NIntegrate$ but it yields $\large 0$ ( zero ) with
$\large\tt Integrate$.

Comment: Wolfram-Alpha [yields zero too](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+%28%5Cln%28x%29%5Carctan%28x%29%2Fx%29%5E2+dx) where it is obvious that the result must be $\large > 0$.

Comment: @FelixMarin: You can find Mellin transform of $\arctan(x)$ by integrating by parts with $u=\arctan(x)$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am upvoting this answer from the standpoint that it is more than just a good answer. You taught me a new way of solving integrals. I am very greatful for that lesson (+1)

Comment: @A.T. Thanks for your valuable comment.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 11):

The function is positive and continuous (except perhaps at the origin) with isolated zeros. The integral is therefore some nonzero, positive quantity.

That Wolfram | Alpha indicates otherwise is quite possibly an error. If you change the upper limit of the integral from $\infty$ to, say $5$, Wolfram | Alpha gives you a positive quantity, further indicating that there may be an error in the way the site is evaluating this integral.

Comment: Oh, well: yet another bug in WA...what else's new? Good answer. +1

Answer (score 10):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{\ln\pars{x}\arctan\pars{x} \over x}^{2}\,\dd x:\
     {\large ?}}$

> $$
> \mbox{With the identity}\quad\int_{0}^{1}{\dd y \over x^{2}y^{2} + 1}
> ={\arctan\pars{x} \over x}\quad\mbox{we'll have}
> $$

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{\ln\pars{x}\arctan\pars{x} \over x}^{2}\,\dd x
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln^{2}\pars{x}
\int_{0}^{1}{\dd y \over x^{2}y^{2} + 1}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd z \over x^{2}z^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over  \pars{x^{2}y^{2} + 1}\pars{x^{2}z^{2} + 1}}\,\dd x
\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\braces{
{y^{-2}z^{-2} \over z^{-2} - y^{-2}}
\bracks{\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over  x^{2} + y^{-2}}\,\dd x
-\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over  x^{2} + z^{-2}}\,\dd x}}\,\dd y\,\dd z\tag{1}
\end{align}

> However, with $\ds{a > 0}$:
>   \begin{align}
> &\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x^{2} + a^{-2}}\,\dd x
> =a\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{x/a} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
> =a\int_{0}^{\infty}{\bracks{\ln\pars{x} - \ln\pars{a}}^{2} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=a\bracks{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
> -2\ln\pars{a}\
> \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x}^{\ds{=\ 0}}\
> +\ \ln^{2}\pars{a}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1}}
> \\[3mm]&={\pi^{3} \over 8}\,a + {\pi \over 2}\,a\ln^{2}\pars{a}\tag{2}
> \end{align}
>   since
>   $\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x = {\pi^{3} \over 8}}$
>   is a [well known result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/862884/85343).

Replacing $\pars{2}$ in $\pars{1}$:
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{\ln\pars{x}\arctan\pars{x} \over x}^{2}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\braces{{1 \over y^{2} - z^{2}}
\bracks{{\pi^{3} \over 8}\,\pars{y - z} + {\pi \over 2}\,y\ln^{2}\pars{y}
-{\pi \over 2}\,z\ln^{2}\pars{z}}}\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[3mm]&={\pi^{3} \over 8}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd y\,\dd z \over y + z}
+{\pi \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
{y\ln^{2}\pars{y} - z\ln^{2}\pars{z} \over y^{2} - z^{2}}\,\dd y\,\dd z
\end{align}
Both integrals can be trivially evaluated:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd y\,\dd z \over y + z}
&=2\ln\pars{2}
\\[3mm]\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
{z\ln^{2}\pars{z} - y\ln^{2}\pars{y} \over y^{2} - z^{2}}\,\dd y\,\dd z&=
4\ln\pars{2} - {1 \over 6}\,\pi^{2} - \half\,\zeta\pars{3}
\end{align}

> Then,
>   \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{\ln\pars{x}\arctan\pars{x} \over x}^{2}\,\dd x}
> ={\pi^{3} \over 8}\,\bracks{2\ln\pars{2}}
> +{\pi \over 2}\bracks{4\ln\pars{2} - {1 \over 6}\,\pi^{2} - \half\,\zeta\pars{3}}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over 4}\bracks{\ln\pars{2} - {1 \over 3}}\pi^{3}
> + \bracks{2\ln\pars{2} - {1 \over 4}\,\zeta\pars{3}}\pi}
> \approx 6.200200822
> \end{align}