# how to evaluate this definite integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}dx$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

For $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}dx$. I considered using residue theorem. But since the function inside is holomorphic except for a removable singularity at the origin. So whatever contour I take, the integral would always be zero. Is there a way that we can get away with the situation and apply residue theorem to do the work?

Comment: if u type ''integral sine squared'' in google, this is the FIRST link:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903117/integral-of-sinc-function-squared-over-the-real-line

Comment: I see... Cuz I'm doing residue theorem recently, so when I see an integral like this, the first thing comes to my mind is solving by residue...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13344/proof-of-int-0-infty-left-frac-sin-xx-right2-mathrm-dx-frac-pi2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Residue Theorem seems unnecessary.

$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(ax)}{x^2}dx$$

$$\implies \frac{dI}{da}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2\sin(ax)\cos(ax)}{x}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2ax)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\implies I(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}a+C$$

But $I(0)=0$, so $C=0$, so $I(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

If you want to use the Residue Theorem, or feel that [Dirichlet's Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/solving-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-frac-pi2?lq=1) is too much to assume, try taking the contour as $Re^{i\theta}$, but rather than a circle with a diameter cutting through $(0,0)$ as part of the path, bring the path above or below the real line. This will circumvent the problems you're having.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.